# Python api call runs fine on local machine but fails when run on Azure VM

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm

I have a Python App Utilizing Azure Vision API. I send an image to Azure Vision-OCR and read the output from there. The usual response is as follows:

```
**{'status': 'succeeded', 'createdDateTime': '2020-11-20T05:07:46Z', 'lastUpdatedDateTime': '2020-11-20T05:07:46Z', 'analyzeResult': {'version': '3.0.0', 'readResults': [{'page': 1, 'angle': 0, 'width': 500, 'height': 265, 'unit': 'pixel', 'lines': []}]}}**
```

When I run the same app on azure and the same call is made from the python app, it returns a response as follows:

```
**{'status': 'running', 'createdDateTime': '2020-11-23T09:23:09Z', 'lastUpdatedDateTime': '2020-11-23T09:23:09Z'}**
```

I don't get a status for success and the `analyzeResult` is non existent. What could be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: what is analyzeResult?

Comment: It’s the portion where the result exists. Basically the result is missing

Comment: can you give more details on the code part

Comment: I'm using a binarized image (black and white) with characters (ex: receipt) and sending it to Azure OCR service to get a string as a response. It works on my local machine without a hassle. But I need to run it on an Azure VM. When it is deployed in the VM, the response from Azure OCR is not received. The above responses are the outcomes. I'm using python "requests" library to make the requests.

Comment: @NethmalWarusamana Have you tried looking at the verbose/debug logs?

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve the issue. The Azure service was processing the request when I was expecting a response. The solution was to poll the server repeatedly after a certain interval (usually seconds) until a successful response was returned. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @NethmalWarusamana Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.